# Splitting a sequence of unknown length into a certain number of sets in R

Tags: r

I have a sequence which varies in length e.g. something like:

```
items <- 1:4
```

I want to split it into every possible combination of `n` number of sets. So say `n` is two, I want to return:

```
Set A    Set B
-----    -----
1        2 3 4
1 2      3 4
1 2 3    4
1 3      2 4
```

etc. The arrangement within sets doesn't matter i.e. the set {`1`, `2`, `3`} is the same as {`2`, `1`, `3`}. Sets cannot be empty.

Best I could come up with (using `permn` from the package `combinat`) is:

```
n <- 2
r <- 1:length(items)
arrangements <- NULL
for (i in 1:(n-1)) {
  A <- r[(1:i)]
  B <- r[-(1:i)]
  arrangements <- c(arrangements, apply(do.call(rbind, permn(1:length(items))), 1, function(z) list(z[A], z[B])))
}
```

Which is fairly useless because it returns sets that are equal i.e. {`1`, `2`, `3`} and {`2`, `1`, `3`} and isn't flexible enough to handle different values of `n`. Anyone have any ideas how I can do this? Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a 'sets' package:

```
require(sets)
power_set(1:4)
sapply( set_power(1:4) , function(x) set_complement(x ,as.set(1:4)) )
list( Set_A = as.list(set_power(1:4)), 
      Set_B = sapply( set_power(1:4) , function(x) set_complement(x ,as.set(1:4)) ) )
```

It includes pairings like  ( {1,2,3,4}, {} ) which is correct from a set theory viewpoint, but you may want to eliminate them as "degenerate". (The way is now clear to generalize this to larger N by working recursively on the Set_B result.)

Answer (score 1):

Here is an other way, that might help you:

```
# Params
n <- 2
items <- 1:4

# Sample
l <- lapply(items, function(x) combn(items, x, simplify=F))
l <-unlist(l, recursive=F)

# devide into sets
tmp <- 1:length(l)
tmp <- split(tmp, sample(1:n, length(l), replace=T))

sets <- lapply(tmp, function(x) l[x])
```